# VB6 (32bit) custom DLL registered in 64bit Windows 10, but cant initate ActiveX object

Tags: excel, dll, vb6, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 32bit VB6 Custom DLL which I was using all along until Excel 2013, Win-7. Now after moving to Excel 2016 on Win-10, the Excel file is rendered un-usable. I have done the Registration of that old DLL file on Win-10 via PowerShell (Admin mode) and it says registration successful. However, when the module in Excel executes creating the Object via CreateObject, it says ActiveX cannot create Object. 
Another surprise that when I try to reference the VB6 DLL from (in Excel) Tools -> Reference, i can reference it and I can access the Class/Functions, but still when I try to execute it, it says the same error about ActiveX.

what else do I need to do in Windows-10 to have it run ?

Answer (score -1):

32 bit programs can only load 32 bit dlls. 64 bit programs can only load 64 bit dlls. This is important. In COM which VB6 and Excel do, you can do non compatible bitness by forcing the wrong bitness dll into dllhost. All calls are marshalled with EXE servers. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/registering-the-dll-server-for-surrogate-activation (note goggle sabotages searches for Windows).